# i want upload main and subreprt in jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

I want upload main and subreprt in jasperserver.but i got error

**Error Message**

> Error filling report
> Error Trace
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$FillResultListener.reportFillError(EngineServiceImpl.java:1262) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:211) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:886) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:842) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1731) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1086) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1015) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:908) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : /reports/sinc/52.Estructura_Opera_IGA_Subreport1 at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:145) at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:107) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:349) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:382) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:307) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2067) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:788) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:298) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:152) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120) ... 10 more

Comment: the '10 more' might be crucial... it contains where it actually fails.

Comment: The bit you need to look at is - /reports/sinc/52.Estructura_Opera_IGA_Subreport1 it can't find the subreport